# Karbonn A52+ automatically turns off constantly

Tags: battery, karbonn

I'm using a Karbonn A52+ running Android 4.2.2. I have been facing a problem, many times, in fact, most of the times, when I'm using my phone, it automatically turns off (Not when the phone is not in use). Then when I try to switch it on immediately, it doesn't.. It switches on only if I try after a while. Sometimes it even requires the charging of the battery, even when it has a decent amount of charge remaining. Sometimes, even such a thing happens:
Phone has 90% battery, it switches off, I reboot, it has 1% of battery. I take the battery out and reinsert, it again has 89-90%. I found an article on the net saying if the phone's testing mode says the battery is healthy (which I did confirm in my phone), most probably it is a software problem.

I tried uninstalling recently installed apps, problem persisted
I removed the SD card, phone worked fine for 10-15 minutes, again switched off
Now when I run the phone WITH sd card, it goes off almost immediately after booting.
I even tried disabling quick boot (which I don't remember when did I turn it on), problem persisted..

I went on and performed a factory reset, phone worked fine for a day (or perhaps less) and the problem started repeating..

So I'm unable to make out whether it's a software or hardware problem..

Shall I go ahead and flash my stock ROM or buy a new battery?

P.S. I have once flashed my stock ROM due to a soft brick around a month or two back..

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a battery issue.

If you think battery is OK, try [recalibrating the battery stats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration&hl=en). (Requires root)

If that doesn't work, yes, the problem is with the battery. Go change it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) (Btw yes, I'm rooted.)

Comment: @TanmayVij:  If you liked the answer, please click both the upvote button and the gray checkmark.